# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE is producing null where hour is 00

Tags: mysql, datetime

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE is producing null where hour is 00. Only the last two lines are importing correctly
Can someone please help me

query:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'test.csv' 
INTO TABLE stats.Counters_ACTIVEUE
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"
IGNORE 1 LINES
  (@varTimeSt,NOMINAL,CELL_ID,IPLATEDL_MS_QCI_9,PDCPSDUDELAY_MSEC_QCI_9,UEACTIVEUL_COUNT_QCI_9,
  UEACTIVEDL_COUNT_QCI_9) SET DAY = STR_TO_DATE(@varTimeSt,'%m/%d/%Y %h:%i');
```

Data:

```
DAY,NOMINAL,CELL_ID,IPLATEDL_MS_QCI_9,PDCPSDUDELAY_MSEC_QCI_9,UEACTIVEUL_COUNT_QCI_9,UEACTIVEDL_COUNT_QCI_9
"09/05/2016 00:00",CE0001,cNum6,5.17,58.285,0.5725,0.9275
"09/05/2016 00:00",CE0001,cNum7,4.9025,40.385,0.17,0.235
"09/05/2016 01:00",CE0001,cNum8,1.8075,23.58,0.2175,0.8925
"08/30/2016 01:00",CE0001,cNum1,5.295,16.34,0.0875,0.17
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`%h` is the format code for the hour in a 12-hour time. An hour in this format must be in the range 1-12; it cannot be 0.

Since your times appear to be in 24-hour format, you probably want `%H`. This should also fix any problems you're having with times after 12:59.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the problem